# Create flash message when validation fails in KeystoneJS

Tags: javascript, validation, model-view-controller, keystonejs, flash-message

I need to make flash error messages change according to the type of validation error. Right now it always says: `Database error` if one of my custom validations doesn't pass.

My custom validations happen in my model, and not in my controllers, so I am not sure how to traverse between the two.

Here is one of my custom validations:

```
User.schema.path('email').validate(function (value) {
if (validator.isEmpty(value) || validator.isEmail(value)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
});
```

The validation works perfectly, it's just the flash message that I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass custom error messages to the `validate` function as well, just pair it with the function by wrapping it in an array, like this:

```
User.schema.path('email').validate([function (value) {
if (validator.isEmpty(value) || validator.isEmail(value)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}, "WRONG!"]);
```

Comment: I initially tried this, but it didn't have any effect. It still only displays `database error`

Comment: that sounds like a bug then